# Add Hidden Input onCheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function

Can someone tell me the best way to go about adding a hidden input field to a form when the user checks a checkbox and remove it if the user unchecks the checkbox?

Below is my form which post to paypal. I have to build all of the fields before the post. I want to include a checkbox  in the form that when clicked will add another hidden field for the "Pet Fee".

```
            <form id='paypalCheckout' action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Demo Vacation Home" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="Demo-Vacation-Home" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="4" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1" />

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Refundable Damage Deposit" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="Refundable-Damage-Deposit" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="3" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1" />

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Cleaning Fee" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_3" value="Cleaning-Fee" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="2" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_3" value="1" />

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="12% Reservation Fee" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_4" value="12%-Reservation-Fee" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_4" value="0.48" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_4" value="1" />

            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_5" value="8% Tax Rate" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_5" value="8%-Tax-Rate" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_5" value="0.32" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_5" value="1" />



            <input type='hidden' name='business' value='juliocpreciado@gmail.com' />
            <input type='hidden' name='shopping_url' value='http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/cart/' />
            <input type='hidden' name='lc' value='en_US' />
            <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_cart' />
            <input type='hidden' name='charset' value='utf-8'>
            <input type='hidden' name='upload' value='1' />
            <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='2' />
            <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD' id='currency_code' />
            <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='|||' />
            <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/store/ipn/'>
            <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/thank-you/' />
            <input id='PayPalCheckoutButton' type='image' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif' value='Checkout With PayPal' />
            </form>
```

Comment: How about you just enable/disable it.

Comment: can you please post what you attempted so far and explain what errors you are getting

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/XuxM5/617/

Comment: I just edited my post to include additional info and my form code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it hidden just replace type="text" with type="hidden" :)

JQuery:

```
    <form id="myForm">
        <input onclick="addRemoveHiddenInput('testId', 'testName', 'testValue')" type="checkbox" id="mc" name="paymentMethod" value="Mastercard"><label for="mc"> Mastercard</label>
    </form>

    <script>

        function addRemoveHiddenInput(id, name, value) {

            if ( $('#' + id).length > 0 ) {

                $('#' + id).remove();  
            } else {

                $('#myForm').append('<input type="text" name="' + name + '" value="' + value + '" id="' + id + '" />');   
            }

        }

    </script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9w5g3swr/

Plain Javascript:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input onclick="addRemoveHiddenInput('testId', 'testName', 'testValue')" type="checkbox" id="mc" name="paymentMethod" value="Mastercard"><label for="mc">Mastercard</label>
</form>

<script>

    function addRemoveHiddenInput(id, name, value) {

        var hiddenInput = document.getElementById(id);

        if ( hiddenInput != null ) {

            hiddenInput.parentNode.removeChild(hiddenInput);
        } else {

            document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML + '<input type="text" name="' + name + '" value="' + value + '" id="' + id + '" />';
        }

    }

</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uu1ftnhg/

Comment: Thank you user3866023 and all of the above users for your input. I will implement this code and hope that this is my solution  :)

Comment: Hey dude, I added your code but for some reason its not working.

Comment: Mhhh strange for me its working...but forked it again. You may try this one http://jsfiddle.net/9w5g3swr/ Tested it in Chrome,Firefox and Opera. Are you sure you have included JQuery lib?

Comment: Well sorry, I thought that I edited my last comment to remove the part about it not working in jsfiddle. However, it still isnt working in the wordpress page that i have implemented it on. Please take a look...  http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/hotels/demo-vacation-home/   Click "Availability" and then click "Book Now". Fill in some dummy data and then you will see your mastercard checkbox near the bottom of the page after you submit the form. Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Yes, it seems Jquery is not working properly...I can rewrite this in plain Javascript.

Comment: Yep, that worked :) I was thinking that jquery might not be loaded properly but then again, that was quite unlikely. Wordpress is funny like that. Different plugins load and reload various versions of jquery and other js libraries and then cause things to break. Well thank you very much for your time and input Sir! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your checkbox : `onChange="if(htis.checked)$("#yourinput").style.display = 'none';else $("#yourinput").style.display = 'block';"`

EDIT : or some thing like things but you got the idea.

Comment: Okay but the field would still exist in the form. I think that I need to actually delete the field from the form when unchecked and add it to the form, when the check box is checked. The code that you posted only shows/hides the field, which is a hidden input anyway.

Comment: use .remov() instead and .append("<input ...>") instead

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<label><input type = "checkbox" id ="myCheckBox"/> Check me!</label>
<span id="hiddenWrapper">
</span>
```

this is the needed jQuery code:

```
 $('#myCheckBox').click(function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        if(true === isChecked){
            $('#hiddenWrapper').html('<input type="hidden" value="myVal" />');

        }
        else
        {
            $('#hiddenWrapper').empty();
        }
    });
```

Take a look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/o7nay5xz/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#randomCheckbox").change(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked"))
         $("#paypalCheckout").append($("<input type='hidden' id='randomId'>"));
     else
         $("#paypalCheckout #randomId").remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger your checkbox to either add or remove the hidden element. Here's a jQuery example:

```
$(function () {
    $("#chkbox").on("click", function () {
      var $this = $(this),
          $input = $('<input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" />'); 

        // Insert the hidden field after the checkbox if checked
        if ($this.prop("checked")) {
            $this.after($input);

        // Remove the hidden field if unchecked
        } else {
            $this.next().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qy1ez1L8/1/

Comment: I think that your code will do the trick. I have 3 other hidden fields that I will have to add/remove in the same manner. Is there a way to easily modify your function so that it can receive 4 different arguments. Basically, clicking the checkbox would add/remove 4 hidden inputs. Each with different values. This is necessary to have 4 inputs that represents one item in the paypal post.

Comment: @AlexWilliams, do your checkboxes have a direct correlation to which input fields need hidden? In other words, when clicking the checkbox, how will I know which 4 fields to add/remove?

After looking at your code sample, it appears that your best bet would be to just disable the hidden fields so that they will not be posted.

Comment: Okay, so this might work. i didn't know that disabling the field would prevent it from being included in the post. Thanx for that info.